# get custom fields value in wordpress while saving the post and save these values in different table in db

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have 2 custom post types created with [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com)

1 is check box, meta key = **google_search**

2nd is a text field, meta key = **search_keyword**

While publishing post I want to check if the google_search is checked and there is a value in search_keyword then

1. Get the search_keyword value and save in to a custom table
2. if search_keyword is empty then use the Title of post and save it into the custom table.

I tried this code in functions.php and post.php (both) but no luck,

```
add_action('save_post', 'googleSearch');

function googleSearch()
{
global $wpdb;

if ( $_POST['google_results'] == "Y") // if checkbox (google_search) is checked
{
    if ($_POST['search_keyword'] != "") // if search_keyword has value
    {
        $sSearchKeyword = get_field('search_keyword');
    }

    else
    {
        //if search_keyword is empty then use post title as keyword.
        $sSearchKeyword = get_the_title( ); 
    }

    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO tbl_keyword SET post_id = '$post_ID',
                                              keyword = '$sSearchKeyword'");
}
}
```

Any help how to get custom field values while saving post and save these values in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are not using the function get_field within a wordpress loop, then you have to define the ID of the post.**

```
get_field('search_keyword', $post_ID);
```

And **var_dump $post_ID** to confirm that this variable is actually holding the post id.

Comment: ok. where should I use this code in functions.php or post.php? Or it is fine to use in any of file?

Comment: Well you are using the action hook so it should be placed withing functions.php.

Comment: glad to help. mark the answer as correct so others can find it as well :)